# How to detect the location of a mouseDown event for a iOS App using Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uievent

**How to detect the location of a mouseDown event for a iOS App using Swift?**

With the following code snippet, I get the error "*Value of type 'UIEvent' has no member 'location'* in scope"**?**

```
import SpriteKit

extension GameViewController {
    
        func mouseDown(with event: UIEvent) {
            
            if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                
                // error here:
                let location = event.location(in: view)
                let node:SKNode = ourScene.atPoint(location)
                
                if (node.name == "creditsInfo") {
                    showCredits()
                }
                
            }   // if let ourScene
    
        }   // mouseDown
    
    }
```

Anybody have a floodlight to shine on this very basic error?

Comment: You ask a question about `UIEvent` and then use the nsevent tag.  What does that mean?  Besides, you mostly use `UIEvent` with `UITouch` in SpriteKit.

Comment: This is confusing. The `mouseDown(with:)` method is from AppKit, not UIKit. You need `NSEvent`, not `UIEvent`. Is this about an iOS app or a macOS app? Please fix your question to make it clear, including the correct code and the correct tags.

Comment: The following line is probably wrong.  let location = event.location(in: view)

Comment: **(1)** an iOS App, **(2)** HangarRash nailed it when he effectively stated that I called an iOS App with a macOS App. iOS Apps deal with touches, not mouse clicks, `obviously` **(3)** I've got touches covered with `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {...}`, **(4)** BUT, I am hung up with how do I see if my code works with touches within Xcode? **(5)** Folk have their mouse linked to their iPad via Bluetooth **?** One last comment ..  there is **no** `func mouseDown(with event: UIEvent)`. The correct call uses `NSEvent` for a macOS App.

Comment: **Silly ole me** .. simulate touches with mouse clicks via settings in the Simulator.